# Swift - Realtime images from cam to server

Tags: ios, swift, real-time, nsdata

I hope someone can help me!
I am making an app that sends frames of the camera to server, and server make some process. App sends 5-8 images per second (On NSData format)

I have tried different ways to do that, the two methods works but have different problems.
I will explain those situations, and maybe someone can help me.

First situation i tried is using **AVCaptureVideoDataOutput** mode.

Code below:

```
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
captureSession.sessionPreset=AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame960x540
captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &error))

let output=AVCaptureVideoDataOutput();
    output.videoSettings=[kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]

let cameraQueue = dispatch_queue_create("cameraQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
        output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: cameraQueue)
        captureSession.addOutput(output)

        videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
        viewPreview?.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer)


        captureSession.startRunning()
```

This view delegates:
**AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate 
AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate**
and call the delegate method:

```
    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBufferRef!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
    {
      let imagen:UIImage=imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
      let dataImg:NSdata=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagen,1.0)
      //Here I send the NSData to server correctly.
    }
```

This method call imageFromSampleBuffer and converts samplebuffer to uiimage.

```
    func imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer :CMSampleBufferRef) -> UIImage {
                let imageBuffer: CVImageBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
                CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0)
                let baseAddress: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, Int(0))

                let bytesPerRow: Int = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer)
                let width: Int = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer)
                let height: Int = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)

                let colorSpace: CGColorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

                let bitsPerCompornent: Int = 8
                var bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo((CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue) as UInt32)
                let newContext: CGContextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, bitsPerCompornent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo) as CGContextRef

                let imageRef: CGImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext)
                let resultImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)!
                return resultImage
            }
```

Here finish the first method to do that, the problem is "infinite memory use", and app crashed after....2 minutes.

I Debug and problem is on **UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagen,1.0)** method, there are any form to release memory after use the method???

Second (and I think best way i found) to do that is using **"AVCaptureStillImageOutput"**

Code below:

```
var stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
            if session.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput){
                stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
                session.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

                self.stillImageOutput = stillImageOutput
            }

var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector:  Selector("methodToBeCalled"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


 func methodToBeCalled(){

            dispatch_async(self.sessionQueue!, {
                // Update the orientation on the still image output video connection before capturing.
                let videoOrientation =  (self.previewView.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).connection.videoOrientation
                self.stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).videoOrientation = videoOrientation
                self.stillImageOutput!.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(self.stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo), completionHandler: {
                    (imageDataSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, error: NSError!) in

                    if error == nil {
                        let dataImg:NSdata= AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
//Here I send the NSData to server correctly.

                    }else{println(error)}
                })
            })

    }
```

This works perfectly and without memory leaks, but when the app takes a Screenshot, the phone makes the tipical sound of "take a photo", and i can not allow it, there are any way to do that without make the sound??.

If someone needs the code i can share the links where i found them.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever manage to solve this problem yourself?

I stumbled upon this question because I am converting a Objective-C project with an `AVCaptureSession` to Swift. What my code does differently is discard late frames in the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, perhaps this is causing your memory problem.

```
output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
```

Insert this line right after you define the video data output and before you create the queue:

```
let output=AVCaptureVideoDataOutput();
output.videoSettings=[kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
let cameraQueue = dispatch_queue_create("cameraQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
```

I am, of course, referring to the first of your two solutions.

Answer (score -3):

There is no way to disallow users from taking a screenshot. Not even snapchat can do that.

Comment: This is not the question :/

Comment: This is what you wrote: " i can not allow it, there are any way to do that without make the sound??."

Comment: I cant not allow the sound, because i can not force user to put on silence the phone....

Comment: @matehegedus I agree with Daniel, you haven't read the question.